# JSON Данные радио вещания по сети

Tags: json, веб-программирование, потоки-данных

Приветствую всех, народ, при создании радио плеера для сайта, возник такой вопрос.

Как и от куда взять адрес вещания того или иного сайта я знаю. Насколько  я знаю, помимо аудио потока, радио станции  в сеть еще выдают поток данных. Вроде бы JSON формате.

Данные такого рода:

1. название станции
2. какая музыка на данный момент играет
3. какая передача идет
4. кто ведущий
5. какая следующая песня
6. следующая передача

В общем своего рода программка, как в детстве в газете.
 я конечно могу ошибаться, но это я подметил на сайтах которые вещают радио и у них есть это информация, значит они это откуда-то берут.

вопросы:

1. Существует ли какое то правило для выдачи такого рода информации в сеть радиостанциями?
   Объясню что имею ввиду под правилами....
   вот например посетитель сайта решил добавить некую Х станцию в свой playлист и я хочу что бы он динамически во время прослушивания своей любимой радио станции имел информацию о том, что слушает...  выше я привел перечень по пунктам.
2. Если не существует этих правил и не существует данного потока, как правильно и грамотно реализовать, что бы посетитель имел всю эту информацию.
   P.S. для любителей поболтать просто, скажу сразу, я в курсе, что могу сам создать JSON файл и сунуть туда вручную всю эту информацию.... мне надо именно динамический...

И еще, если я не совсем понимаю и вопрос неправильно звучит, просто отзовитесь и разъясните если не лень... 
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Название трека часто передают прямо [в StreamTitle в icecast-потоке](https://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/radio_protocols.txt.html), а всё остальное обычно самодеятельность без конкретного стандарта

Comment: andreymal, благодарю, если бы ты знал сколько я искал ответ на этот вопрос, суть я понял...  значит в потоке передается только название трека и больше ничего?

Comment: По крайней мере на практике я ещё ни разу не встречал радио, передающее в потоке что-то помимо названия трека (хотя не исключено что такие есть)

Comment: посмотри тут. http://101.ru/radio/channel/85 у них информация кто ведущий, на других сайтах встречал какая следующая песня... и подобное...какая передача на данный момент...  как ты думаешь это в ручную делается по договоренности со станцией?  ну может быть, хотя мне кажется, что логичнее эту информацию выдавать потоком

Comment: Я ковырялся на 101.ru, у них тоже только StreamTitle с названием трека. Всё остальное какими-то сторонними путями

Comment: узнать бы эти сторонние пути....  в любом случае, благодарю, ты внес существенный вклад в мой вопрос...

Comment: Ой, а 31 августа вопрос-то был абсолютно другой, очень нехорошо так делать

Comment: меня заблокировали, я не мог задавать вопросы, я как раз этот вопрос и изменил, и  получил возможность задавать вопросы, меня разблокировали...  буду писать вопросы по новой, как подобает хорошему тону на сайте....